# How to redirect one domain to the other with SSL?

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, ssl-certificate, cname-record

I have two domains (example.com and example.co.uk).
The .com one is the "head" and has servers behind him.
What I want to do is redirect all traffic from the .co.uk to the .com domain.

I looked at the internet and made a CNAME record in the DNS and the redirect work!

....but, I have SSL enabled on the .com version and normal HTTP is not allowed. The browser is complaining about the certificate as it should be (as the .co.uk is not the same as .com).

Question: How can I redirect the traffic from .co.uk to .com with a SSL on the .com domain?

P.S. I understand that one of the options is to redirect with a 301, but I would like to aviod that because I would need a server on the .co.uk for only redirects (not very cost efficient ) !!

Comment: I don't get the `I looked at the internet and made a CNAME record in the DNS and the redirect work!` part, that should create an *alias*, right? Can you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

Get an SSL certificate that uses [subjectAltName](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubjectAltName) and is valid for both example.com and example.co.uk, and then you can run SSL name-based virtual servers and do the 301 redirect all on the same server. Or if your server and all your clients support [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) you can do the same with two different certificates (the most likely clients that won't support it are IE on Windows XP and Chrome on Android versions before 3.0).

Answer (score 0):

A HTTP Redirect is the solution here.

No, you won't need any server at `.co.uk`: just make your DNS point to the same servers at `.com` and configure those to redirect each connection to `.co.uk` to `.com` (the configuration will depend on which type of servers you have there).